# Show page, show associations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

i try to find out how i can show associations deeper than one level.

Show at my FORM, i just done it there:

```
  form do |f|
f.inputs "Details" do
  f.input :name
  f.input :item_category
  f.input :resource
  f.input :status
end
f.inputs "Actions" do
  f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
  f.has_many :item_actions, :allow_destroy => true, :heading => 'Planets', :new_record => true do |obj|
    obj.input :action
    obj.input :status
    obj.input :_destroy, :as=>:boolean, :required => false, :label=>'Remove'
    obj.has_many :item_action_skills, :heading => "Skills" do |ias|
      ias.input :skill
      ias.input :level
    end
  end
end
f.actions
```

end

You can see, i show has_many :item_actions and going one level deeper to  item_action.item_action_skills. On this form is works perfect.

Now i'll want it on the show page too. My code:

```
  show do |obj|
attributes_table do
  row :name
  row :item_category
  row(:resource) {|obj| status_tag((obj.resource ? 'yes' : 'no'), (obj.resource ? :ok : :error))}
  row(:status) {|obj| status_tag(obj.status_string.first, obj.status_string.last) }
end
panel "Actions" do
  table_for obj.item_actions do
    column :action
    column(:status) {|obj| status_tag(obj.status_string.first, obj.status_string.last) }
  end
end
active_admin_comments
```

end

I write table_for, but how to go now to the next association?
I want the item_action.item_action_skills.

I have no idea. Any idea?

Thanks!

Ruby 1.9.3
Rails 3.2.14
ActiveAdmin 0.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
panel "Actions" do
  table_for obj.item_actions do
    column :action
    column(:status) {|obj| status_tag(obj.status_string.first, obj.status_string.last) }
    column("skills"){|resource|
        table_for resource.item_action_skills do
            column(:your_column)
        end
    }
  end
end
```